# Nessus XML-RPC API

Tags: nessus

I'm trying to build an application using Nessus XML-RPC API.

I will need to achieve the following:

1) Control start,stop,resume scans in a nessus server from my application.
2) After scan is completed, get all the report data of the scan and store it in a local database

Can any one help?

Thank you,
Sash.

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @Rob yes, but XML-RPC is outdated now. Nessus now offers REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the Nessus XML-RPC API documentation: http://static.tenable.com/documentation/nessus_5.0_XMLRPC_protocol_guide.pdf